# How to keep the house cool from inside by covering the window panes?

Tags: windows

I am thinking of covering the window panes with 5 fold newspapers.

What other inexpensive items/materials can be used to cover the window panes for keeping the house cool from inside?

Comment: Why not some thick shades, or curtains?

Comment: @Tester101, in India, DIY takes on a new meaning.  I'm amazed by the creativity there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're writing from India, so the standard US answer of installing light blocking cellular blinds may not apply to you.

Consider using a thin material that reflects light instead of absorbing much of it, such as aluminum foil.  If you want it to look nice, you can stack the foil between a light piece of paper for the outside (so the neighbors aren't blinded by the reflection) and cardboard (for rigidity).

Comment: Thanks, actually I am living on rent, therefore it is better for me to have some temporary solutions. I am afraid that in heavy windy conditions, the foil might get damaged. What do you say? And I am not concerned about how it looks. :)

Comment: The aluminum foil works, I've done it myself, but I like the idea of backing it with cardboard. Maybe making a sandwich out of a few layers of cardboard and foil and then taping it to each individual frame would work. Do you run AC?

Comment: Gluing it to the cardboard will hopefully minimize damage (even something like a box for food).  Only attach it to the top of the window to let it flap in the breeze (and attach it well enough so it doesn't blow away).

Comment: Isn't newspaper a bad conductor of heat?

Comment: Newspaper will insulate, but it still absorbs a lot of the light, rather than reflecting it away.  That said, it's good enough for Air India pilots, so it can't be that bad of an idea :) http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/26/business/global/26airindia.html

Comment: @B Mitch You are good at dry humor ;) Thanks for help. I am thinking of sticking the foil on the inner side of the windows, thus when the wind blows, the foil won't get torn away. :)

Comment: how about foil-faced XPS? Not terribly expensive. Cut to size, insert into window. Perhaps cover the back with some fabric to make it look nice.

Comment: Hey, One more question, in winters do I have to remove that silver foil? Anything (on windows) which will keep the house warm in winters?

Comment: You want the light for heat in the winter, so I'd take the foil down.  Then, block any drafts from the windows.  Here, that involves weather stripping and maybe a plastic wrap.  If you're improvising, a rolled up towel along the bottom of the window sill is a start.

Comment: What are "drafts"? Gaps? and what is "weather stripping"? BTW, I am not a native English speaker. :)

Comment: Your English is better than my Hindi.  Drafts are gaps that allow cold air to pass.  Weather stripping that we get in the US is usually a foam or rubber material that can be compressed in the gap to form an air-tight seal.

Comment: Because you didn't add any `@Anisha` in your comments, I couldn't get notified for the last comment of yours. Yesterday I refreshed this page just for the sake and accidentally saw your comment! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Anisha, I miss notices all the time around here.  But that may be because my name has a single letter at the start, maybe I should take out the space.

Comment: May be you should use your actual full name? ;)

Comment: @Anisha, I only avoid doing so because I discuss ideas related to my startup on other SO sites that I'd like to avoid potential competitors discovering.

Comment: Alright, as your wish. :)

Comment: I did use Aluminium foil in the past summers, and they "did work" superbly. The temperature downfall was remarkably noticeable. Thanks to you.

Comment: @AnishaKaul You're welcome, and thanks for the follow up.

Comment: :) One more question: I have a "wooden" door near the windows. Have already covered the windows with the foil. I was wondering should I cover the outside of the door with foil too? Will that help greatly?

Answer (score 4):

[Foam Panels](http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials-Insulation-Sheathings/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbaxx/R-100317820/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)

I'm not sure that this would be available to you locally, but this is what I use on my bedroom. Cuts easy and has a reflective side and is very cheap. Works well enough to keep the Florida heat out of 50 year old leaky windows.

Comment: That looks cool, but I am not sure if it'll be available here!